# How to run program 10000 times in java and find average?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to run a method 10000 times, add the value on top of itself and then divide by 10000 to find an average. The value that needs to keep adding is numOfSteps. I wrote a for loop inside the main method, right now Im just testing it with 3 times. It makes the method run 3 times, but I cannot find a way to get the value of numOfSteps and add it to itself each time the program runs. How can I go about this?

```
public class AssignmentTwelve2 {
    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of steps you want to find average for: ");
        int step = key.nextInt();
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            randomWalk(step);
        }
    }

    public static void randomWalk(int step) {
        int position = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int numOfSteps = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        int steps;

        while ((step * -1) < position && position < (step * 1)) {
            System.out.println("position = " + position);
            steps = rand.nextBoolean() ? -1 : 1;
            position += steps;
            numOfSteps++;
        }

        System.out.println("position = " + position);
        System.out.println("Number of steps:" + numOfSteps);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about the scope of your variables.

Comment: What do you think would happen if `int numOfSteps = 0;` was a field?

Comment: is 10000 your input `step`?

Comment: randomWalk must return int instead of void. Then you will use randomWalk's output.